# Print Cforms form as pdf

Tags: pdf, plugin-cforms

I have created a form using [Cforms from Delicious](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/). The client asked me for an option to print this form as a pdf. I tried some plugins such as [Print Friendly and PDF Button](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/printfriendly/) that make it possible to add a pdf or print button, but this button is subsequently added to all pages and most of the time the form does not appear on the print preview /printout. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from a dev at [WordPress Questions](http://wpquestions.com/) I got this solved. In `wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms.php` we added

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
```

which loaded all the necessary data from the folder `html2pdf` which has all the files based on code from [html2pdf.fr](http://html2pdf.fr)

Further in the same file after `$newcontent .= substr($content,$last);` we have code to pdfy the code:

```
 $pdfContent = '<table width="560" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">';  
    for($i = 1; $i <= $field_count; $i++) {

        if ( !$custom )
            $field_stat = explode('$#$', $cformsSettings['form'.$no]['cforms'.$no.'_count_field_' . $i]);
        else
            $field_stat = explode('$#$', $customfields[$i-1]);

        $field_name       = $field_stat[0];
        $field_type       = $field_stat[1];
        $field_required   = $field_stat[2];
        $field_emailcheck = $field_stat[3];
        $field_clear      = $field_stat[4];
        $field_disabled   = $field_stat[5];
        $field_readonly   = $field_stat[6];


        if($field_type == 'fieldsetstart') {
        $pdfContent.='<tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr><tr><td  align="left" colspan="2" valign="middle"><span style="width:100pxheight:30px;float:left">' . stripslashes(($field_name)) . '</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr>' ;
        }

    else if($field_type =='textarea') {
    $pdfContent.='<tr><td  align="left" valign="middle"><span style="width:100pxheight:30px;float:left">' . stripslashes(($field_name)) . '</span></td><td valign="middle"  bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><span style="width:300px;height:30px;float:left"><textarea  cols="40" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></textarea></span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr>' ;
    }   

    else{
    $pdfContent.='<tr><td  align="left" valign="middle"><span style="width:100pxheight:30px;float:left">' . stripslashes(($field_name)) . '</span></td><td valign="middle"  bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><span style="width:300px;height:30px;float:left"><input type="text" style="width:350px;height:30px;"></span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td>&nbsp;</tr>' ;
    }
```

and

```
$pdfContent.='</table>';
//echo $pdfContent;
 try
            {
                $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
                $html2pdf->writeHTML($pdfContent, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
                $html2pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__) . '/html2pdf/pdf/form.pdf','F');
            }
            catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
                echo $e;
                exit;
            }
```